# Positioning issue not working for me

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Probably a simple fix, but after messing with this issue for 2 hours I'm turning to you guys...

Below is a link to what I'm playing with. My issue is, the side content is not aligning correctly.

http://back2lifedesigns.com/WordPress-Client-Test/

I need the left aside to move left so it is not blocked by the rollover image. Everything I tried either did nothing, made it worse, or messed up other parts of the site.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```
#bar-left {
  left: -15px;
}
```

adjust the pixel value as needed...

Comment: I tried that as well, but it doesn't seem to move any. Currently it is at -18px and tried -18px important! as well.

Comment: with as much rep as you have, you should know better than to answer low-quality questions like this.  At least give the OP feedback about the fact that links-only to their website are no good, because once the site is [fixed|deleted|removed|updated] the link (and the question) have zero value.

Comment: New here, not sure how to post the code like in the response.

Comment: use this :

#bar-left{left: 16px!important;}
#bar-right {right: -16px!important;}

Comment: I tried that, but no change. The weird part is, #bar-right shows in the CSS pane when inspecting the page. However, #bar-left does not show, like it's not detecting it?

Comment: Went back through and sure enough, there was a stray character in the CSS above it. :) Now it works!